# How to set a value of a panda dataframe between two indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to set a value to a panda dataframe based on the values of another column. In a nutshell, for example, if I wanted to set indices of a column `my_column` of a pandas dataframe `pd` where another column, `my_interesting_column` is between 10 and 30,  I would like to do something like:

```
start_index=pd.find_closest_index_where_pd["my_interesting_column"].is_closest_to(10)
end_index=pd.find_closest_index_where_pd["my_interesting_column"].is_closest_to(30)
pd["my_column"].between(star_index, end_index)= some_value
```

As a simple illustration, suppose I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10, 20), columns=list('A'))
df["B"]=np.nan
>>> df
    A   B
0  10 NaN
1  11 NaN
2  12 NaN
3  13 NaN
4  14 NaN
5  15 NaN
6  16 NaN
7  17 NaN
8  18 NaN
9  19 NaN
```

How can I do something like

```
df.where(df["A"].is_between(13,16))= 5
```

So that the end results looks like

```
>>> df
    A   B
0  10 NaN
1  11 NaN
2  12 NaN
3  13 5
4  14 5
5  15 5
6  16 5
7  17 NaN
8  18 NaN
9  19 NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.loc[start_idx:end_idx, 'my_column'] = some_value
```

I think this is what you are looking for

```
df.loc[(df['A'] >= 13) & (df['A'] <= 16), 'B'] = 5
```

Comment: The main issue i am having is finding the start and end indices

Comment: can you share the top 5 columns of your dataframe, `df.head(5)`?

Comment: please see my new clarifications to the questions

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am gonna test it on my dataset